# oracle sql developer most common value with ties

Tags: sql, oracle

At the moment I have:

```
select username, email
   from memberinfo
   where username = (select username, count(username) as big
                        from rankinginfo
                        group by username
                        order by big desc);
```

I am trying to return the most common username, and have so far been concentrating on the count(username) list.

I can order the list but I can't seem to work out how to single out the top result.

It is really important that if there are 2 (or more) usernames at the top that they are both (all) returned.

I have tried using TOP and LIMIT but both without success. Any ideas? Sorry I know this must be extremely simple, but I have spent way to long trying to figure it out. I'm very new to SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sub query in your question should return only one username. But currently it is returning multiple usernames and its count too. Modify it to something like this.

```
SELECT username
  FROM (SELECT   username, COUNT (username) AS BIG
          FROM rankinginfo
      GROUP BY username
      ORDER BY BIG DESC)
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

**EDIT** : If there is a tie for top spot between more than one user, you will have to assign ranks to each user and select the users with rank 1.

```
SELECT username, email
  FROM memberinfo
 WHERE username IN (SELECT username
                      FROM (SELECT username, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(username) DESC) user_rank
                              FROM rankinginfo
                             GROUP BY username)
                     WHERE user_rank = 1);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Much appreciated! Do you know how I could return multiple usernames if there were an equal most common username?

Answer (score 0):

No LIMIT in Oracle until 12c I'm afraid:

```
select username,
       email
from   memberinfo
where  username = (
         select username
         from   (
           select   username
           from     rankinginfo
           group by username
           order by count(*) desc)
         where rownum = 1);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Much appreciated!
Do you know how I could return multiple usernames if there were an equal most common username?

Answer (score 0):

This really is a job for window functions (what Oracle calls analytic functions). You can use `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` to return ties, or `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the top value of `username`, allowing Oracle to choose arbitrarily in case of ties. Note that I also use `COUNT()` as a window function. I would have done simple aggregation had `email` not also been returned by the query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT username, email, username_cnt
         , RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY username_cnt DESC ) AS rn
      FROM (
        SELECT username, email
             , COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY username ) AS username_cnt
          FROM memberinfo
    )
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

Hope this helps.